# Login by Yahoo! account

Tags: zend-framework, single-sign-on, yahoo-api

I'm using Zend Framework 1.x to developer my Web Application. I want to create "Login by Yahoo! account" function. These options below are what I tried:

1. Using [Yahoo! Socical API Client](http://developer.yahoo.com/social/sdk/php/), but with PHP 5.3, it usually catch error "strict standards" about static and non-static, object and non-object methods.
2. I tried another way, using [Zend_OAuth](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.oauth.introduction.html). But, this time, I got consumer_key_rejected error.

Both ways, I used OAuth to get user info.
Please help me to solve this problem or show me other ways to create "Login by Yahoo! account" function.

Thanks

**EDIT:**
With the second ways, if I just want to get basic user profile (Email, Name, Gender) it got consumer_key_rejected.
When I register for new scope (Contacts), I got oauth_token and oauth_verifer, but I stayed there, I don't know how to do next step to get user info.